# Craft 3 Registration Form Success Redirect

Tags: form, redirect, registration

Is it possible to redirect the user to a specific page after they successfully complete the front-end registration form (before activation)? I've tried adding:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/save-user">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="registration-successful">
```

But it currently just redirects back to the home page. I really need to redirect the user to a page that prompts them to check their email for the activation link. It currently feels a bit broken.

Am I missing something?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL needs to be hashed. Try using `{{ redirectInput('registration-successful') }}`

As documented here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/functions.html#redirectinput-url

Comment: Udo, thank you so much. That worked perfectly.